# grouping by different entity in doctrine orm select query

Tags: oracle, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I'm trying to select users whose latest access token expired greater than 5 days ago. Here's what I have. I know I'm close but I keep getting the following oracle exception:

> ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression

```
<?php
        $tokens = $em
            ->createQueryBuilder()
            ->select('a', 'u', 'MAX(a.expiresAt) AS HIDDEN latest_expiration')
            ->from(AccessToken::class, 'a')
            ->join('a.user', 'u')
            ->where('a.expiresAt < :deadline')
            ->groupBy('u')
            ->orderBy('latest_expiration', 'DESC')
            ->setParameter('deadline', time() + (5  * 86400)) // 5 days
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, building on what @cstotzer suggested, you need to be SELECTing only things that are GROUPed or are aggregate functions, which as you attempted (since you don't actually want all the individual `AccessTokens`) means removing `a` from the SELECT list.  But in your case you can't remove the reference to `a` because that's the root entity that your query is concerning.

So, instead I think you need to turn it around, and instead of asking for

```
All the accesstokens where the most recent token for a user is too old, and the users that go with those tokens
```

you should ask for

```
All the users whose most recent access token is too old
```

I think you want something like this (untested):

```
<?php
        $tokens = $em
            ->createQueryBuilder()
            ->select('u', 'MAX(a.expiresAt) AS HIDDEN latest_expiration')
            ->from(User::class, 'u')
            ->join('u.accessTokens', 'a')
            ->where('a.expiresAt < :deadline')
            ->groupBy('u')
            ->orderBy('latest_expiration', 'DESC')
            ->setParameter('deadline', time() + (5  * 86400)) // 5 days
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult();
```

Comment: this looks good except that my `User` class does not hold references to access tokens. :/

Comment: Well, my (not sarcastic!) suggestion would be to add one! Very simple Doctrine relation, wouldn't have any effect on the DB schema. Without that, you can't do the query that way round, so you'd need to return non-GROUPed user/access data and then process in PHP to get unique users.

Answer (score 0):

When using a GROUP BY clause the fields in the SELECT clause need to either match those in the GROUP BY or an aggregate function (such as MAX) has to be applied to them. This means, you need to remove the column 'a' (which by the way is a relation and not a column) from the select clause.

Comment: if i remove the 'a' i get the following: `[Semantical Error] line 0, col -1 near 'SELECT u, MAX(a.expiresAt)': Error: Cannot select entity through identification variables without choosing at least one root entity alias.`